# How much is the web push notification daily or hourly limits for any browser?

Tags: push-notification, web-push

All browsers suggest to limit the number of web push notification else the account will get blocked.

However how much is too much? Could not find any official document which mention of any specific number allowed.

Any idea what is the limit number for firefox, chrome, edge?

Comment: Where have you read that? There aren't any limits if you send normal push notifications. The problem with rate limit is when you don't display a visible notification (known as silent push)